# Fancybox 3 как по клику на кнопку открыть галерею с inline контентом

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Нужно чтобы по кнопке открывалась галерея inline блоков с листалкой влево и вправо подскажите пожалуйста как это реализовать?

Нашел пример http://jsfiddle.net/VZd7c/ но он на 3 версии не работает.

```
<a id="fancy-1" class="btn btn-blue" data-src="#popup-1" href="javascript:;">Смотреть</a>
<div id="popup-1" style="display: none;">
    <div data-fancybox="gallery-1">
        <h1>Заголовок 1</h1>
        <p>Текст 1</p>
    </div>
    <div data-fancybox="gallery-1">
        <h1>Заголовок 2</h1>
        <p>Текст 2</p>
    </div>
    <div data-fancybox="gallery-1">
        <h1>Заголовок 3</h1>
        <p>Текст 3</p>
    </div>
</div>
<a id="fancy-2" class="btn btn-blue" data-src="#popup-2" href="javascript:;">Смотреть</a>
<div id="popup-2" style="display: none;">
    <div data-fancybox="gallery-2">
        <h1>Заголовок 1</h1>
        <p>Текст 1</p>
    </div>
    <div data-fancybox="gallery-2">
        <h1>Заголовок 2</h1>
        <p>Текст 2</p>
    </div>
    <div data-fancybox="gallery-2">
        <h1>Заголовок 3</h1>
        <p>Текст 3</p>
    </div>
</div>
```